# $A_i\subsetneq B_i,i\in I\implies \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\subsetneq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}B_i$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I$ be an arbitrary index set and $A_i\subsetneq B_i,i\in I$.
I was wondering if the following statement is true.

$A_i\subsetneq B_i,i\in I\implies \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\subsetneq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}B_i$.

Is there any counter example?

I was reading the book, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-29794-0 to study Axiom of choice and 4 other equivalent statements and in the proof of one implication, the author writes $\subset$ instead of $\subsetneq$. Although that didn't seem to affect the proof, I was wondering if that was the strict inclusion more precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at $I := \{1,2\}$ and $B_1 = B_2$. Can you construct a counterexample where both unions yield the same set?

**Spoiler:**

> The statement fails for $A_1 := \{1\}$, $A_2 := \{2\}$ and $B_1 := B_2 := \{1,2\}$. The statement is wrong since we have equality.